# How do you add a subscription group in Google Play Console (for managing tiers like upgrades/downgrades)?

Tags: android, google-play-console, android-billing

I've been trying to find any documentation about this but haven't found anything. [You can clearly have different tiers for subscriptions](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#change) but I can't find a way to set it up in the Google Play Console. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution for that?